# Table function not printing in the shell

Tags: python, printing

I am very new to python coding, but when I try to run this file, I don't get any output in the shell. why is that?

```
test = ['please', 'work']
test
```

shouldn't this print `['please', 'work']` in the shell?

Answer (score 1):

If you have it on a file:

```
test = ['please', 'work']
print(test)
```

that will print the content.

if you opened `python` then you can do:

```
>>> test = ['please', 'work']
>>> test
['please', 'work']
```

Comment: when I test for elements in the table , I get no output as well if I type it in a file. how do I get an output if I want to do all the code in the file?

Comment: if your file is called `main.py` on the terminal you execute `python main.py`

Answer (score 0):

Do
`import dumper`
and
`dumper.dump()` 
for debug

Answer (score 0):

Please Use print function to print data

```
test = ['please', 'work']
print (test)
```